# Is it possible to "embed" a structure of variable type into another structure? (GCC)

Tags: gcc, struct, embed, mplab

Is it possible to embed a structure of varying type inside another structure in C?

Basically I want to do something like this.

```
struct A { int n; void *config; }

struct AConfig { int a; char *b; }
struct BConfig { int a; float b; }

const struct A table[] = {
    { 103, (void*)(struct AConfig){ 1932, "hello" } },
    { 438, (void*)(struct BConfig){ 14829, 33.4f } }
}
```

Is this possible in C or do I have to define the structures separately?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it doesn't work like that. You need explicit storage for each structure:

```
struct A { int n; void *config; };

struct AConfig { int a; char *b; };
struct BConfig { int a; float b; };

struct AConfig ac = { 1932, "hello" };
struct BConfig bc = { 14829, 33.4f };

const struct A table[] = {
    { 103, &ac },
    { 438, &bc }
};
```

#### Edit:

Another possibility is to utilize a `union` and C99 (`-std=c99`) named initializers:

```
enum config_type { CT_INT, CT_FLOAT, CT_STRING };

union config_value {
    int int_value;
    float float_value;
    const char* string_value;
};

struct config {
    enum config_type ctype;
    union config_value cvalue;
};

struct config sys_config[] = {
    { CT_INT, { .int_value = 12 }}, 
    { CT_FLOAT, { .float_value = 3.14f }}, 
    { CT_STRING, { .string_value = "humppa" }}};

void print_config( const struct config* cfg ) {
    switch ( cfg->ctype ) {
        case CT_INT: 
            printf( "%d\n", cfg->cvalue.int_value ); break;      
        case CT_FLOAT:
            printf( "%f\n", cfg->cvalue.float_value ); break;
        case CT_STRING:
            printf( "%s\n", cfg->cvalue.string_value ); break;
        default:
            printf( "unknown config type\n" );
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a union:

```
struct AConfig { int a; char *b; };
struct BConfig { int a; float b; };
struct A {
    int n;
    union {
        struct AConfig a;
        struct BConfig b;
    };
};
```

Note that `a` and `b` are in the exact same space in memory.  So if you are going to use the `A.a` you should not use `A.b` and vice versa.

Since this is an anonymous union, you can reference both `a` and `b` as if they were direct fields of struct A:

```
struct A sa;
sa.n = 3;
sa.b.a = 4;
sa.b.b = 3.14;
```

Answer (score 0):

It would work if BConfig had a float pointer to b.

By the way, maybe you need to refactor your code to fit to C syntax.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct { int n; void *config; } Config;

typedef struct { int a; char *b; } AConfig;
typedef struct { int a; float *b; } BConfig;

int main(void) {
        AConfig A;
        BConfig B;
        A.a= 103;
        A.b= "hello";
        B.a= 438;
        B.b=(float *) malloc (sizeof(float));
        *(B.b)= 33.4f;
        const Config table[] = {
                { A.a, (void *) A.b },
                { B.a, (void *) B.b }
        };
        printf("Hi\n");
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may prefer a union.  My union syntax is a little rusty, but something like this:

```
union config { char* c; float d; };
struct A {int n; int a; union config b;};

const struct A table[] = {
    {103, 1932, { .c = "hello" } },
    {14829, 438, { .d = 33.4f } }
};
```

You need C99 for the designated initalizer (the .c or .d in the table), and obviously some way to tell if you're accessing a char* or a float, but I assume you have that covered somewhere else.